# Tell whether video is loaded or not in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, video, loaded

So, I've been using a listener on

```
document.getElementById("video").buffered.length
```

to see if it's greater than `0` for when a video's loaded or not. This works for a very small video, and only in Google Chrome. It doesn't work in Firefox at all. Any ideas for how to get this to work?

I essentially want to wait till 3 seperate videos are loaded to take a specific action, how do I go about this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Try this:

```
var video = document.getElementById("video-id-name");

if ( video.readyState === 4 ) {
    // it's loaded
}
```

Read here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/readyState

Comment: Which browsers support that property?

Comment: @JaredFarrish According to this [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5_Media%29), the support is complete (The WebKit column is empty, but I would be surprised if their implementation was behind Mozilla's/Opera's).

Comment: @ŠimeVidas how this can be used if there are more than 1 videos. ? thanks

Comment: This answer doesnt make sense. This is not really listening for changes. This is only going to run when the page first loads and if it's ready right away it will only work.

Comment: @Omar You are correct. I can delete my answer when a true solution is posted.

Comment: @Omar You are generalizing the use cases. I am saying this because in my media preload function, this solution fits perfectly, as I poll for load of various audio,video,image files periodically.

Answer (score 32):

**UPDATE:**

As others have mentioned, my original solution below does work but it can lead to performance issues and some unpredictability in its behaviour.

Therefore I recommend listening to the `loadeddata` event.
Read more here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadeddata_event

```
const videoElement = document.getElementById("my_video");

videoElement.addEventListener('loadeddata', (e) => {
   //Video should now be loaded but we can add a second check

   if(videoElement.readyState >= 3){
       //your code goes here
   }

});
```

**==================================**

**INFERIOR SOLUTION:**

I find using `setInterval` works for actively listening to when the `readyState` of the video changes by checking every half-second until it loads in.

```
checkforVideo();

function checkforVideo() {
    //Every 500ms, check if the video element has loaded
    var b = setInterval(()=>{
        if(VideoElement.readyState >= 3){
            //This block of code is triggered when the video is loaded

            //your code goes here

            //stop checking every half second
            clearInterval(b);

        }                   
    },500);
}
```

If you're not using ES6 just replace `() =>`  with `function()`

Comment: Great answer! FYI all this is doing is checking a simple property of the video element. It uses very little processing power, so there's really no need to wait a half second between checks. You can change it to 10 milliseconds and catch the video at almost the exact moment it's loaded.

Comment: This is badass.

Comment: This answer is fantastic but it blocks the main thread and I am trying to display a spinner there... the spinner animation freezes every second.

Comment: @DuckDucking you're right. Using `setInterval` might get the job done but it's far from ideal. I updated my answer with an new and improved solution that shouldn't cause performance issues.

Comment: It's 2023 now and the "inferior" solution is the only one that worked for me on Firefox.  loadeddata did nothing even though it is listed on MDN as working in all browsers.

Answer (score 7):

To make this into a listener, under normal circumstances, you'll want to listen to the suspend event. It's triggered when download is paused or stopped for any reason, including it's finished.

You'll also want to listen to playing for the cases when the content is already loaded (like, from cache)

```
video.addEventListener("playing", function() {
    console.log("[Playing] loading of video");
    if ( video.readyState == 4 ) {
        console.log("[Finished] loading of video");
    }
});
video.addEventListener("suspend", function(e) {
    console.log("[Suspended] loading of video");
    if ( video.readyState == 4 ) {
        console.log("[Finished] loading of video");
    }
});
```

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Media_events

Answer (score 3):

Use onloadeddata event on the video element. It checks whether the video is loaded or not. See [this reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/loadeddata_event) for more information.

> The loadeddata event is fired when the frame at the current playback position of the media has finished loading; often the first frame.

```
var video = document.getElementById("video");
video.onloadeddata = function() {
    // video is loaded
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: Well it didn't take me long to research this hint, and in my case it turned out to be the best solution.    <video onloadded="mystuff()"... > allowed me to set up a pause, a wait and then a resume to solve choppy video due to low buffering on a live stream

Answer (score -1):

I find other way

```
    const video = document.querySelector('video');

video.addEventListener('canplaythrough', (event) => {
  console.log('I think I can play through the entire ' +
      'video without ever having to stop to buffer.');
});
```

source - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/canplaythrough_event